# Center bitmap text to a rectangle with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to center a piece of text to a rectangle.

I found this [example](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/24_text_alignment/index.php), but I'm struggling to understand what it does.

It is not too hard to achieve this, I just need to know how do I find the width and the height of the text after being drawn, but I cannot find this anywhere.

To draw the text, I do it char by char:

```
static void drawText(std::string str, float x, float y, float z) {
    glRasterPos3f(x, y, z);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, str[i]);
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way, but it is my first program using OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raster fonts are awful, this will not work in modern OpenGL just so you know - you need to use texture-mapped triangles to implement bitmap fonts now-a-days. If you are just starting out, legacy OpenGL may work for you, but you will find that things like raster pos are not supported in OpenGL ES and core OpenGL 3+.

That said you can sum up `glutBitmapWidth (...)` across all of the characters in your string, like this:

```
      unsigned int str_pel_width = 0;
const unsigned int str_len       = str.size ();

// Finding the string length can be expensive depending on implementation (e.g. in
//   a C-string it requires looping through the entire string storage until the
//     first null byte is found, each and every time you call this).
//
//  The string has a constant-length, so move this out of the loop for better
//    performance! You are using std::string, so this is not as big an issue, but
//      you did ask for the "best way" of doing something.

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
  str_pel_width += glutBitmapWidth (GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, str [i]);
```

Now, to finish up this discussion, you should be aware that the height of each character is identical in a GLUT bitmap font. If I recall, 18 pt. Helvetica is probably 22 or 24 pixels high. The distinction between pt. size and pixel size is supposed to be for DPI scaling, but GLUT does not actually implement this.

Comment: Thank's for answering, this might solve my problem. Is there anyway to know also the height, since `glutBitmapHeight` seems do not exist?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos: Yeah, I forgot to include that in my answer. See my updated answer :)

Comment: I found another function: `glutBitmapLength` that given the font and the string, returns me the width of the whole string. Thank you.